# Crossfade Loop in AudioKit

Tags: swift, audiokit

Does AudioKit provide any options to crossfade a loop?  I've experimented with using an AKBooster to fade in/out an AKSequencer, however I set a varying tempo/rate on the fly which complicates when to start the fades.  AKWaveTable provides a great looping option, however I'm not sure if there's any way to create a "soft" loop that crossfades from it.  I'm looking to soft-loop the following example:

```
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 let mixer = AKMixer()
 let wavePlayer = AKWaveTable(file: (try! AKAudioFile(readFileName: "sample.mp3")), startPoint: Sample(44100), endPoint: Sample(44100), rate: 1, volume: 1, maximumSamples: 0, completionHandler: {}, loadCompletionHandler: {})
 func play(){
    wavePlayer.play()
    }
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    wavePlayer >>> mixer
    AudioKit.output = mixer
    wavePlayer.loopEnabled = true
    wavePlayer.play(from: Sample(44100))
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
    }
    play()
  }
}
```

Thanks!